# How do you deploy ("Publish") a website to Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How do you 'Publish' a website from VS (Visual Studio 2019), to Azure?

I set up an Azure account, and my website is implemented in ASP.NET MVC Core. I went thru the tutorials and every gd one is showing steps out of some previous version that fails to help guide me today.

I want to host this on an Azure App Service. Do I have to create an App Service from within Azure Portal, first, or does VS do that for me? What do I put for these other fields (image is attached) ?

[image: The VS Publish dialog]
VS pre-entered this value for "Server:", and for "User name:" it put $Designforge  (what the heck is that?!)

I am just trying to do the simplest-possible way, right now.

Should I put my Azure user-name and password on this dialog? When I do, and click on "Validate Connection" I get the failure-message that you see in this screenshot.

I've really no idea how to proceed with this most simple of tasks. Hanging my head in abject shame.
Thanks for any help,
James

Comment: Hi, the problem comes from you input the wrong username and password. Have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know what you are facing about.

I find your password is too short so I guess you press the wrong password.

[image]

This is what you meet ,right?

**Solution:**

Go to your portal, select get publish profile.

[image]

Download and paste the username and password to your vs publish dialog.

[image]

Do you understand now?

Comment: @JamesHurst Happy to help.